# Does mysql optimize result table to avoid duplicate values

Tags: mysql, resultset, mysql-connector, database-optimization

In case of a JOIN, especially in a one to many relationship, the result set will very often contain a lot of duplicate information in the result.

For example,

| TABLE_A_ID | TABLE_A_FIELD_ONE | TABLE_A_FIELD_TWO | TABLE_B_ID | TABLE_B_FOREIGN_KEY | TABLE_B_FIELD_ONE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | MARK | POLIO | 41 | 12 | SHOE |
| 12 | MARK | POLIO | 42 | 12 | SHIRT |
| 12 | MARK | POLIO | 43 | 12 | BOOT |
| 12 | MARK | POLIO | 44 | 12 | HAT |
| 12 | MARK | POLIO | 45 | 12 | GLOVE |

As you can see, `12`, `MARK`, `POLIO` are sent six times in a row. In my real situation, I am noticing that I am sending the same data thousands of times in a row, sending over 20x the amount of data over the wire from db to app server, and 20x as much memory.

I was about to start optimizing the **** out of it, but then I realized that it is very likely that mysql drivers already do optimize this, for example by sending only table b columns, and table a columns for when `TABLE_B_FOREIGN_KEY` changes.

It is really optimized this way or another way, or should I stop using joins and instead do round trips to the DB?

Comment: _As you can see, 12, MARK, POLIO are sent six times_ Well 5 actually :)

Comment: _likely that mysql drivers already do optimize this_ NO, the result is correct based on the query you wrote

Comment: _or should I stop using joins and instead do round trips_ Absolutley NOT, the round trips are worse than shifting a bit of extra data up the wire

Comment: _The result is correct_, but we are talking about optimization, not correctness.

Comment: Ok, so exactly how were you considering you were going to optimise this

Comment: 1. Send the entire result set as an aggregate json array
2. Two round trips. In my case it's not a bit of extra data, but **20x** the data, since I have four tables joined, possibly sending 10,000 records.

Comment: I might suggest that 10,000 rows is a bit much for people to read on a screen! Is this to generate a report perhaps

Comment: we are drifting off topic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238409/discussion-between-f-khantsis-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: The answer is no. MySQL delivers the algebraic result. There is no so-called 'optimization' of duplicate values. You can achieve that with `SELECT DISTINCT`, `GROUP BY`, etc.

Comment: Once you redesign the output to have less redundancy, you will see a way to have less redundancy in the network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

When the duplicates are in a single table, consider adding `UNIQUE (col)` to that table.  This forces uniqueness (at Insertion time) based on `col`.  If Uniqueness is determined by a combination of columns, then `UNIQUE(col1, col2, ...)`.

More likely you need `DISTINCT` to dedup whole rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, ...
    FROM ...
    JOIN ... ON ...
```

But there are cases where the dedupping should be done in other ways.  Let's see your `SELECT`.  (I'm thinking of `GROUP BY` or a 'derived table'.)

Comment: I need the resulting column to have dupes, I am just hoping that it sends less data over the wire and takes less memory.